# GridView display more then 1000 rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ado.net

I use `GridView` to display data from DB. First I query data from DB to `list<list<string>>`, sort use linq, copy this array to `DataTable` and bind `DataTable` to `GridView`. But if in `DataTable` more then 1000 rows - it works very long or not works (error in browser).
How to fix this?

UPDATE i use rowspan in columns and create a delete buttons to all rows, and if i use paging wiil it works?

```
<div>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnDataBinding="GridView1_DataBinding" OnRowDeleted="GridView1_RowDeleted" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" > 

     <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Number" ItemStyle-Width="200px" > <ItemStyle Width="200px" > </ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" ItemStyle-Width="200px" > <ItemStyle Width="200px" > </ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nameoid" ItemStyle-Width="200px" > <ItemStyle Width="200px" > </ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>

                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return DeleteConfirm();" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
                           <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" Value='<%#Bind("Number") %>' />

                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

     </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Do you expect 1000 rows to be fast?  Why not split it up into pages of 50 or 100 that the user (and the page) can reasonably process.

Comment: Please do some progressive fetch loading technique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are doing lots of server side code in one round trip time. You should make it lesser so that page could show the result in grid view.

Here are few things on which you should work:

1. There is no need to store first in list then data table and then sorting. You can directly use the DATAVIEW class to sort the result from DB.
2. I think you should not display all 1000 record in grid view in a single page. You should use PAGING in grid view. This is also in built functionality of grid view by this you can show number of record in a one grid view page as you want..

For reference how to do this there is complete example. Follow the below link
http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource12-How-to-implement-paging-and-sorting-in-aspnet-Gridview-control.aspx

**UPDATE**:

If you want to delete a row in gridview with a link button on each row. Then follow the below article

[enter link description here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1619/how-to-perform-edit-update-and-delete-operation-in-gridview)

You can put the `UpdatePanel` outside of gridview. First try to use the above code (from link), then try to add update panel. If you feel any difficulties ask here.

Comment: if you are using grid view then you can directly add the delete button for each row.No coding or manual work required! there are inbuilt select,update,delete buttons!

Comment: Is there any special requirement for using row span and adding the delete button?

Comment: No, i use UpdatePanel for button, when user click delete button - in DB removed this rows, in table this button becomes inactive.

Comment: use the inbuilt delete button and put the grid view in the update panel.

Comment: update question, code how i create table. If i put gried view to update panel whats happend?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use Lazy loading pattern with your GridView . 
You can refer to :
[LazyLoadUpdatePanelusingTimerControlAJAX](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Delay-Load-Lazy-Load-UpdatePanel-using-Timer-Control-in-ASP.Net.aspx)

or you can implement custom paging

[Custompaging](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Custom-Paging-in-ASP.Net-GridView-using-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can  use paging in your grid view having grid size of say 10,20,30 to accommodate large amount of data so that the page doesn't crash.

Try referring to this example 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106678/Display-Large-Amount-of-Data-in-GridView-with-Sear